# How to eliminate duplicate expressions in SELECT clause?

Tags: sql-server

I have a query which looks like below -

```
select distinct datepart(yy, a.date_created) as year, datepart(mm, a.date_created) as month, concat(month, '-', year) as monthyr
from dbo.assignment a
```

So, what I am trying to do here is, I am getting year part of date, then month part of date and then I need third column to be as month-year.

Meaning, I should have three columns when I run the query:
Supposing I have date as 09/11/2015

Result should look like below when I run this query:

```
Year    Month    YearMonth  
2015    09       09-2015
```

But when I run the query, I get errors:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6  
Invalid column name 'month'.  
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6  
Invalid column name 'year'.
```

I get the correct results using the below query:

```
select distinct datepart(yy, a.date_created) as year, datepart(mm, a.date_created) as month, concat(datepart(mm, a.date_created), '-', datepart(yy, a.date_created)) as monthyr
from dbo.assignment a
```

I wanted to avoid using datepart again while concatenating. So, i was trying doing something like first query.

Is there any other way I can achieve same results?

Thanks

Comment: (I *know* there are duplicates, but they are being elusive.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the duplicate expressions a derived query (`select .. from select ..`) could be used. It is otherwise *not possible to access an identifier introduced in the select output clause in the same select.*

However SQL Server should optimize both just the same and eliminate the 'duplicate' expression. I'm fairly certain it'd also produce the same plan even with the distinct moving - but look at the *actual query plan* to be sure.

A query with a derived select might look like:

```
select
  year, month, concat(month, '-', year) as monthyr
from (
  select distinct
    datepart(yy, a.date_created) as year,
    datepart(mm, a.date_created) as month
  from dbo.assignment a
  ) t
```

While this can lead to a cleaner query in some cases, the biggest improvement is probably adding newlines and indenting.

Answer (score 1):

A subquery would be slightly more efficient:

```
select *,concat(month, '-', year) as monthyr
from (
      select distinct datepart(yy, date_created) as year
                     , datepart(mm, date_created) as month
      from dbo.assignment) a
```